# Andoird: Obtener miniatura de un video en el dispositivo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy tratando esta forma pero no me carga ninguna imagen.... alguna idea???

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

```
   // var item = ListaVideo[position]
    holder.Titulo.text = ListaVideo[position].Titulo

   // holder.Video.setVideoPath(ListaVideo[position].Path)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, VideoActivity::class.java).apply{
            putExtra("posicion", position)
        }
        context.startActivity(intent)

        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(ListaVideo[position].Path)
        Glide.with(context.applicationContext).load(uri).thumbnail(0.1f).into(holder.Miniatura)



    }
}
```

Comment: Como obtienes el video, desde una url o se encuentra en el proyecto? como estas tratando de obtener la minuatura?

Comment: @Elenasys obtengo el video atraves de ListaVideo[position].Path la miniatura con el glide pero no me funciona

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, tienes una lista y esa miniatura ¿cuándo debe mostrarse?  Porque en el código parece que al hacer click en la celda, inicias una nueva Activity y es en ese listener cuando pasas al imageView la imagen... si lo haces sólo al hacer click pues es normal que no aparezca en el momento de mostrar la lista

Comment: intenta con load(ListaVideo[position].Path).frame(0) en glide. Si sale negro puede ser que el frame es negro esa parte.

Comment: Podrìas imprimir si  ListaVideo[position].Path en verdad tiene la ruta correcta de la Imagen , esto puede ser la causa del problema

Answer (score 0):

```
val thumbnailTemplate = try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            contentResolver.loadThumbnail(uri /*uri del video*/, Size(256, 256) /*tamaño de la miniatura*/, null)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }catch (e:Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
    thumbnailTemplate?.let {
        Glide.with(root).load(it).centerCrop().into(imageView)
    }
```

Solo funciona para API > 29, no encontré cómo hacerlo para menor. Espero igual te sirva.